# Describing the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-8,2x-6)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How can one describe the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-8,2x-6)$? What is meant by *describing* it? How does an element of the ideal generated by $x-8$ and $2x-6$ look like?

Comment: An element of $(x-8,2x-6)$ is a sum of the form $(x-8)f(x)+(2x-6)g(x)$. Describing the quotient ring means, in this case, to identify it with a simpler ring like $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$ by using ring isomorphism theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a well known isomorphism theorem we have $$\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x-8,2x-6)}\simeq\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-8)}{(x-8,2x-6)/(x-8)}.$$ But the evaluation morphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb Z$, $x\mapsto 8$, gives rise to an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-8)\simeq\mathbb Z$. This isomorphism sends (the residue class of) $2x-6$ to $2\cdot8-6=10$, so $$\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x-8)}{(x-8,2x-6)/(x-8)}\simeq\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z.$$

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to see that $(x−8,2x−6)=(10,x+2)$
Further $\mathbb{Z}[x]=\mathbb{Z}[x+2]$
So

$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x−8,2x−6)=\mathbb{Z}[x+2]/(10,x+2)=\mathbb{Z}_{10}$$

Comment: $(x−8,2x−6)=(10,x+2)$ can be helpful, but not necessary.